# mock multiprocessing Pool.map in testing

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, monkeypatching

I want to write a test case for a method in my code mocking the multiprocessing part using pytest.

This the code and I need to write a test for simulation method.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool


class Simulation:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def simulation(self):
        pool = Pool(processes=self.num)
        val = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

        res = pool.map(self.sim, val)

        return res

    def sim(self, val):
        return val * val
```

Here is the test case.

```py
import pytest

from multi import Simulation


@pytest.fixture
def sim():
    return Simulation(2)


@pytest.fixture
def mock_map():
    def map(self, val1=1, val2=2):
        return [val1, val2]

    return map


def test_sim(sim, mock_map, monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr('multiprocessing.Pool.map', mock_map)
    res = sim.simulation()
    assert res == [1,2]
```

When running the test I get the out put as [1,4,6,16,25] where I need to mock the out put as [1,2].

Comment: Even if the patching would work, `Pool.map` has a completely different signature than your `mock_map`. It will raise an exception on first usage attempt.

Comment: Yes, That's correct. I just want to mock entire Pool.map function. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, via e.g. `monkeypatch.setattr(multiprocessing.pool.Pool, 'map', mock_map)`.